# Why two options for an integration?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

From table of integrals I saw this:

$$\int \sin^max\cos^nax\,dx=
  \begin{cases}
\displaystyle -\frac{\sin^{m-1}ax\cos^{n+1}ax}{a(m+n)}+\frac{m-1}{m+n}\int \sin^{m-2}ax\cos^nax\,dx \\[8pt]
\displaystyle \frac{\sin^{m+1}ax\cos^{n-1}ax}{a(m+n)}+\frac{n-1}{m+n}\int \sin^max\cos^{n-2}ax\,dx 
  \end{cases}
$$

Why there are two options? Does it matter which one I choose?

Comment: Which one would you choose if you had to integrate $\sin^{12} x \cos^4 x$?

Comment: Is it correct to choose the one that allows me to get rid of an integral part as soon as possible?

Comment: both are correct, and both are obtained via simple integration by parts.. the only difference is which factor you "integrate" and which one you "differentiate"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gives you flexibility. Suppose you have $$I = \int \sin^{100}x\cos^3x\, dx$$

Going one way, you'll reduce it to $$[\ldots] + k\int \sin^{100}x\cos x\, dx$$
which you can solve immediately by substituting $u=\sin x$. But going the other way, you'll have
$$[\ldots] + k\int \sin^{98}x\cos^3 x\, dx$$
which isn't as useful. So a reasonable rule of thumb would be to choose the integral that reduces the smallest exponent.